# React Three Fiber - Pointer events on bufferGeometry don't work if using index

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm working in React Three Fiber using an orthographic camera to visualise a 2d shape (a square in the example but it should support polygons as well).

But the problem is that as soon as I add `indexes` to my indicies the pointer events stop working.

Here is the example code with both a working example without `index` and a broken one with `index`
https://codesandbox.io/s/pointer-actions-with-indices-xt3f7k?file=/src/App.js

My guess is that I'm missing something obvious but I'm not that experienced with Three.js/React Fiber.

```
export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#33ffaa");

  const positions = new Float32Array(
    [
      [0, 0, 1],
      [100, 0, 1],
      [100, 100, 1],
      [0, 100, 1],
    ].flat()
  );

  const indices = new Uint32Array(
    [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [0, 2, 3]
    ].flat()
  );

  const onPointerEnter = () => {
    setColor("#9933ff");
  };
  const onPointerLeave = () => {
    setColor("#33ffaa");
  };

  return (
    <Canvas flat={true} orthographic={true}>
      <mesh
        onPointerEnter={onPointerEnter}
        onPointerLeave={onPointerLeave}
        position={[-100, -100, 0]}
      >
        <bufferGeometry>
          <bufferAttribute
            attach="index"
            array={indices}
            count={indices.length}
          />
          <bufferAttribute
            attach="attributes-position"
            array={positions}
            count={positions.length / 3}
            itemSize={3}
          />
        </bufferGeometry>
        <meshBasicMaterial color={color} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
      </mesh>
    </Canvas>
  );
}
```

I've tried googling but can't find info about pointer events associated to bufferGeometry.